# Django: Code from Database not rendered before being displayed

Tags: html, django, browser

I'm using the following code on a Django page...

```
{{ event.info }} <p>hi</p>
```

{{ event.info }} has a value of

```
<p>hi</p>
```

Yet on the html page the following is displayed

```
<p>hi</p> hi
```

I need the browser the process the code from {{ event.info }} instead of displaying it as text.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the safe filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

```
{{ event.info|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `safe` filter: `{{ event.info|safe }}`